# How to convert Cognito Pool User with Group Role to IAM credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm working on the 1% of problems where I actually have a cognito pool with groups assigned to users and those groups have IAM roles. This is a special case where all the users are internal and actually want to directly have unfettered access to AWS. Now after the user logs the token has the group and group role in it. How do I get AWS credentials from this token?

No, I don't want an identity pool, since that would defeat the purpose of the IAM role in the group. So how is this supposed to work?

I'm vying for a working code snippet that generates the credentials or passes the token to the javascript AWS SDK.

Answer (score 0):

The role in the group only exists as a suggestion to the cognito identity pool, it does not provide the benefit of replacing it. Additionally, to use this, contrary to the docs, the `Logins` property must be specified.